# Why I am facing some problem with voice RSS api

Tags: javascript, html, audio, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I am using Voice RSS api for text to speech, I am facing some problems with this api

this is [my code](https://codepen.io/Thakur92411/pen/KJYOza?editors=1011)

When try to say Hi or Hello in microphone it works on fine , but with other sentence it dose not reply

```
 if( itsValue == 'what is your name' || itsValue == 'may I have your name' || itsValue == 'how may I address you' || itsValue == 'who are you' || itsValue == 'may I know your name' || itsValue == 'how can I call you'){
              alert('df')
              var text = encodeURIComponent("Opening...please wait");
              document.getElementById("voiceresult").setAttribute("src", audioUrl+text);
              document.getElementById("voiceresult").play();
            }
```

Comment: Please provide the part of `index.html` that is throwing the error

Comment: Please check i have provided my codepen link

Comment: Hi probably worthwhile including the relevant portion of the code inline rather than through a link. Means those who are helping you don't have to context change between web pages.

Answer (score 1):

Here's why the error happens: `raw.githubusercontent.com` is serving your JavaScript file as plaintext (`text/plain` instead of `application/javascript`). Your browser have strict MIME type checking enabled, so it throws an error, because it asks for some JavaScript but receives what appears to be plaintext.

Unfortunately, you don't have any control over `raw.githubusercontent.com`, so you have two solutions:

- Disable strict MIME type checking on your browser
- Use an alternative to `raw.githubusercontent.com`, like [jsdelivr](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ranacseruet/webspeech/build/webspeech.min.js)